# Text on big image and small images

Tags: html, image, text

I finally found code to make a image gallery.

However, I don't know how I can put text on it.

I've tried many things but those doesn't work or aren't responsive.

Code:

```css
img {
  float: left;
}

img.large {
  width: 70%;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

img.small {
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#"><img alt="Test Large" class="large" src="http://prizem.dreamhosters.com/test/test_large.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img alt="Test Small 1" class="small" src="http://prizem.dreamhosters.com/test/test_small_1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><img alt="Test Small 2" class="small" src="http://prizem.dreamhosters.com/test/test_small_2.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gxb33ex5/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be "cleaner" ways to do it, but something that I would probably do to achieve what you're out after is to define the image sources in the CSS file, so that you can make a image based on divs instead of the  tags, which in its turn will allow you to place any other content inside them. Like so:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: inline-table;
  
  }

/* Large image */
.img1 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('http://prizem.dreamhosters.com/test/test_large.jpg'); 
}

/* Small image */
.img2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('http://prizem.dreamhosters.com/test/test_small_1.jpg'); 
}

/* Small image */
.img3 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('http://prizem.dreamhosters.com/test/test_small_2.jpg'); 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="#">
<div class="img1">
<p>
My Text
</p>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#">
<div class="img2">
<p>
My Text
</p>
</div>
</a>

<a href="#">
<div class="img3">
<p>
My Text
</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the text's position to absolute?